# Is it OK to put programming requests on SO?

Tags: discussion

So, is it OK to put small programming requests on StackOverflow? Say, like, could someone write something that could do this in 50 lines or less?

Or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't necessarily think that is a legitimate use of StackOverflow. We already have contention about homework problems. Asking someone now to actually write a solution for you for a problem (without at least making an honest attempt yourself) is not likely to be accepted widely by the community.

Comment: OK, I definitely understand that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: +1, I usually dislike people that come to "ask teh code" (did I spell it good ?)

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for someone to write your code for you, the answer is NO.  If you are looking for something like the numerous [code-golf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/so-weekly-code-golf) questions, the reactions are mixed, but I say that for a Friday afternoon, it is a good time had by those interested.