# Why is a question about the pronunciation of an algorithm name off topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic

I'm trying to get some insight into why this question about [the pronunciation of Kruskal's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694705/how-is-kruskal-pronounced) is off topic.

Are pronunciation questions not welcome on SO?

Comment: How is someone's surname unique to the programming field? @pep

Comment: Pronunciation is a weirdly regional thing... I've been places where they pronounce pepsi "coke"!

Comment: We all know you correctly pronounce it as "soft drink" you bird feeder @shog9

Comment: That's crap, @random - any right-thinking drinker knows it's "soda pop".

Comment: [**README**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46694/lack-of-consistency)

Comment: No, really, though important as it might be **for you**, do you honestly (honestly!) think that pronouncing the name wrong will affect your code? No? Ok, so it has nothing to do with programming. And if you have to tell this to someone, you can always spell it out. I hope someone won't ever judge my programming skill on how I pronounce a guy's name (nor anything, for all that matters...Hell, we in Italy pronounce "MySQL" wrong, or "italianized", but that doesn't mean the queries will be easily injected). I bet you will pronounce Fibonacci wrong: so I must say your code is horrible, sir.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Are pronunciation questions not welcome on SO?

That question seems to have answered itself, don't you think? To reiterate: no, pronounciation questions are not remotely on-topic on SO. To quote [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions):

> ### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
> who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
> questions have a bit of `source code` in them, but if your question
> generally covers...
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession ...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

The pronunciation of *any word* — regardless of the word's relevance to programming — does not fall into this category.

To quote [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) just a little bit more:

> ### What kind of questions should I not ask here?
>
> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
> problems that you face.

'Nuff said.

---

[OP question:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125563/why-is-a-question-about-the-pronunciation-of-an-algorithm-name-off-topic#comment339000_125564)

> Guys, I understand your point that this is not a question about solving a programming problem. But do you really not think that pronunciation questions are useful for programmers?

[My response:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125563/why-is-a-question-about-the-pronunciation-of-an-algorithm-name-off-topic#comment339001_125564)

> **not on Stack Overflow.** SO has evolved to be, first and foremost, about solving programming problems, not about "being useful to programmers."

Comment: _The pronunciation of any word — regardless of the word's relevance to programming — does not fall into this category._ How did you come to that conclusion? I would think that the question is "practical, answerable, and unique to the programming profession"..

Comment: @pepsi How is it unique to the programming profession? Isn't it a question that potentially every native English speaker can answer? Do programmers have a unique pronunciation for "Kruskal"? I know all the secret handshakes, but... ;P

Comment: Well then, [that just ate up a bunch of my close votes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) for the day. Too bad it'll probably cost me [the reps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780194/how-do-you-pronounce-jni). Some of the `[pronunciation]`-tagged questions *are* good ones, though, so look out if anyone decides to go on a closing spree.

Comment: Over 60 days with at least +3 on that pronunciation answer, @RobHruska you've won the retroactive lottery and will keep your rep. After taxes.

Comment: @YannisRizos I've heard it pronounced in more than one way. It's not uncommon to pronounce the names of people with the same names to differently. Programmers will have heard the pronunciation of 'Kruskal' in the context of the algorithm, which is important. If I asked my neighbor whose friend was named Bob Kruskal, it may not be the same pronunciation.

Comment: @pepsi (1) having an objectively correct answer is not a sufficient condition for a question to be on-topic. I could ask "How many cylinders are there in a V-8 automobile engine" but you can bet that won't fly on SO. (2) I don't see how that helps your case. This is not a "programming problem" in the sense of "I'm trying to do `XYZ` with code but I am having problems doing so."

Comment: @pepsi `Programmers will have heard the pronunciation of 'Kruskal' in the context of the algorithm, which is important.` Well, almost every programmer has heard Dijkstra's name in a programming context, but I highly doubt that programmers who aren't fluent in Dutch have any idea of how [Edsger Wybe Dijkstra is pronounced](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Dijkstra.ogg). And how about Bjarne Stroustrup?

Comment: *"I must solve this problem. Wait, what's this? An algorithm? Fantastic! **Precisely** what I've been looking for. But... (removes sunglasses, lowers voice) **My God**... how is it pronounced? Now I'll -never- be able to solve this problem."*

Comment: @YannisRizos But there are one or two common pronunciations that you can use and not get funny looks from your peers. And that seems like useful information to be on SO..

Comment: Guys, I understand your point that this is not a question about solving a programming problem. But do you really not think that pronunciation questions are useful for programmers?

Comment: @pepsi **not on Stack Overflow.** SO has evolved to be, first and foremost, about solving programming problems, not about "being useful to programmers."

Comment: @pepsi - They're *interesting*, but probably not useful. If there's a pronunciation disparity when a couple co-workers are discussing something, they'll figure out what each other are talking about in, like, four seconds, and move on with the actual task at hand. If it's between two people on the Internet, well... tough to have a pronunciation problem there.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I think you hit the nail on the head with that. Want to put it in your answer?

Answer (score 5):

**"Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology)"** is generally specified as on-topic question in [The English Language and Usage Stack Exchange FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq).

You may check if your specific case fits there:

> #### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> The English Language and Usage Stack Exchange is for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts. [Questions on the following topics](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-off-topic-here) are welcomed here:
>
> - Usage, word choice, and grammar
> - Etymology (history of words’ development)
> - Dialect differences
> - Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology)
> - Spelling and punctuation
> - Problems encountered by people learning English
>
> But please, don’t ask any questions about these topics. They are out of scope for this site.
>
> - Please proofread my document ("are there any mistakes in this text?")
> - Languages other than English (including translation)
> - How to improve my English
> - How to name this function/variable in my program
> - Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature
> - Peeving about grammar disguised as a question
> - "Explain this joke to me", except in the case where the crux of the joke relies on an aspect of English covered by one of the welcomed topics above.
>
> ...

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what [MДΓΓ БДLL said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125564/132734), most potential questions about pronunciation would seem to either be "general reference" (e.g. ["Java"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904547/how-do-you-pronounce-the-word-java)) or controversial (e.g. ["SQL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886/sql-pronunciation)), with little in between.

Controversial questions just end up as "Not Constructive" with a bunch of IMHOs.

General reference questions would just clutter the site. If a question about one algorithm name / initialism / programming language is on topic, almost all would be on topic by precedent, and that'd just lead to ridiculousness. *"How do you pronounce A#?"*,  *"How do you pronounce ActionScript?"*, *"How do you pronounce Ada?"* ...

Comment: Agreed all the way.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL - But how do you pronounce "Agreed"?

Comment: - `A g r e e d` -