# We have puzzle, code-golf, and now code-chess tags. Can we migrate them all somewhere else?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

We  now have a new noise tag, code-chess, courtesy of [this subjective question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296664/code-chess-fibonacci-sequence)

The thin end of the wedge (code-golf) is well on its way to becoming a gaping wound. Now would be an excellent time to migrate these and similar 'puzzle' non-questions elsewhere. I suggest all of it be moved to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ so they can hate on it for a while ;-)

Comment: Waiting for [code-aussie-rules-football]...

Comment: I like how there's a highly voted comment asking why people are downvoting it if it is CW. I wasn't aware that CW meant you were not allowed to express your opinion that the question is not a good one.

Comment: -1  _  `code-golf` seems to clearly fall within Stack Overflow. I mean the answers are code, and the question is how to write a certain piece of code.... [programming Q & A](http://stackoverflow.com/about). --------- There's [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-golf/info) as to how frequently questions should be asked.... of course I don't want `code-politics` (spaghetti code, obv) etc etc.... Maybe a separate thread about just `code-chess`? ------------ Note: there's only 1 `code-chess` post currently.

Comment: @Grace Note: +1, +1, +1, +1, +1... sorry, looks like only one upvote is sticking.

Comment: @Shog9: Personally, I'm a fan of `[code-darts]`.  Just keep making random changes to your code until it works.

Comment: @Peter:  There's a difference between code-golf and code-chess.  Code golf can be objectively judged.  The question as to how to do something in the shortest number of characters is actually programming-related, and answerable objectively.  Code chess was to find an ingenious, not short, solution, and the only problem I have with that is choosing between "subjective and argumentative" or "not a real question".  Well, that and the fact that I was outvoted.  Despite downvote and vote to close, that question is still out there.

Comment: @Peter, I don't think anyone's arguing that code golf isn't programming-related. Seems to me that more people debate whether it is a question that can be objectively answered.

Comment: @Shog that's already been released in Australia. Me, I'm excited about `[code-chess-boxing]` and `[code-extreme-ironing]`.

Comment: I just reverted the tag edit.  Somebody's obviously trying to get himself a taxonomist badge, hoping that this will turn into a long-running series.

Comment: @David - My downvote was purely to protect `code-golf` and say that it is not a "gaping wound." I'd up vote a move to ban `code-chess` as subjective and argumentative.

Comment: related: [Where do code golf questions belong?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74658/where-do-code-golf-questions-belong)

Answer (score 5):

A "gaping wound"? That question (and it's tag) has been with us since February. There's still only one of them.

I see no huge surge in "code chess". Or why "now would be an excellent time" - given it's been around for seven months.

To me, this sounds like another rehash of the [old debate about code golf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/so-weekly-code-golf). Which as far as I am aware, is still accepted by the community.

Comment: It's not the same as code golf; code golf is actually not subjective.

Comment: now would be an excellent time because, like code-golf, waiting only encourages it

Answer (score 1):

Note that where Code Golf belongs was [discussed on Meta.Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/where-do-code-golf-code-challenge-questions-belong), and while there was no consensus as to where they belong, there was consensus that they *don't* belong on Programmers.SE.

Code Golf questions seem to have a home on Stack Overflow, and bringing up that they should all be closed as off-topic is beating a horse that's been dead since old times. The only way I can see that happening is if the [Code Golf Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles) gets off the ground.

Comment: interesting - so the programmers don't want it, and the area 51 proposal has insufficient support..so what does this say about code-golf et al? ;-)

Comment: It says that you are not a code-golf fan.  Of course a sane code-golfer isn't insane enough to do this *every day*.  Once a month/week, something like that.  Please don't grind this place in a meatball of average.  Jeff's "let's have a little fun *once* in a while" message is getting lost.  This cannot possible be more annoying than the flood of crappy questions from India, properly tagged crap is much easier to ignore.

Comment: @hans w/r/t flood of crappy questions, remember that question downvotes *matter* .. more than you might think. hint, hint.