# Where do code golf questions belong?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, code-golf, software-engineering-se

Just had an exchange regarding this SO question:

[Code Golf: Numeric Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659511/code-golf-numeric-ranges)

Since reading Jeffs' [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/) about programmers and the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) on programmers, I was under the impression that code golfing questions should be asked on it rather than on SO.

In particular I mean the sections that explicitly allow:

- Programming puzzles

However, as @SLaks notes in his comment, there is a distinct lack of these questions on programmers, while new ones do come up all the time on SO.

So, where should code golf questions go?

Comment: Personally, I think they should go in /dev/null (`code-golf` appears on my SO ignored tags for a reason).

Comment: related: [We have puzzle, code-golf, and now code-chess tags. Can we migrate them all somewhere else?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64511/we-have-puzzle-code-golf-and-now-code-chess-tags-can-we-migrate-them-all-somew)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code golf questions go to Stack Overflow as stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67780/why-is-code-golf-now-the-domain-of-programmers-se).

You might be interested in [Code Golf & Programming Puzzles](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles) proposal.